# How to change left margin / padding text error on android TextInputLayout material.textfield

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android

I need to remove error text left padding / margin on TextInputLayout material.textfield.

Any idea how to do this?

need like this error text with no padding
[image]
Default padding is same with TextInputEditText padding (has left padding):

[image]

I try extend IndicatorViewController but it final class

Comment: No way. It has the same padding of the EditText (and it allows the guidelines)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did say I am relatively new to this, I assumed that you would be able to modify the padding attributes within the theme. I did find another solution *possibly* but it brings both the floating label and the error text over. It would need to be setup dynamically but messing with

```
textInputLayout.setPadding(-40,0,0,0);
```

changed it so that it would line up closer to the left margin.

Comment: It doesn't work, because the EditText and the error TextView have the same padding.